# How to install Airplayer, Airplay or any AirPort Emulator on Windows?

Tags: windows, installation, airport

Is it possible to install [Shairport](http://mafipulation.org/blagoblig), or any Airport Emulator, on Windows?
I want to stream music, photos and/or videos from my iPhone to Windows directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got [Airplayer](https://github.com/PascalW/Airplayer) working on XBMC on Win7 x64.

1. Install XBMC and enable control from network (System -> Network -> Services -> Allow XMBC via UPNP & HTTP)
2. Download python 2.7 for win32
3. Download setup-tools from: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools
4. Put C:\Python2.7 and C:\Python27\scripts in the Windows Path. 
   (Go to control panel > System > advanced system settings > environment variables

   > search for the Path variable in the lower System variables area of the dialog 
   >   and add both paths seperated by an semicolon (;).
5. Download https://github.com/PascalW/Airplayer/archives/master and extract to disk
6. Open an cmd window and type: easy_install pip
7. in the same window type, navigate to the airplay script
   folder and type: pip install -r requirements.txt
8. also in the same window type: dns-sd.exe -R MyComputer _airplay._tcp . 6002
9. configure the settings.py in the airplayer folder.
10. run airplayer from the cmd window: python airplayer.py
11. run XBMC
12. Open a Youtube video from your iOS from the official YouTube video and look for the Airplay icon.

If you restart your computer, you will have to execute steps 8, 10 & 11 again :)

[There is a way to launch everything needed as a windows service](http://pascalw.github.com/Airplayer/airplayer-windows-service.html), I will investigate that. If someone figures it out, please update this guide (its a community wiki) or post a reply!

[Source](http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?t=80400&highlight=airplay&page=11)

Answer (score 1):

Answering myself: 
I could'nt compile ShairPort for windows, but I found another solution.

I installed [AirMedia Player](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2010/12/airmediaplayer-hack-enables-airplay-video-streaming-from-iphone-ipad-ipod-touch-to-windows-pc.html) on my windows 7. It allowed me to view videos from the YouTube App on the iPhone instantly on my windows PC. Then, I installed [AirVideoEnabler](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2010/11/airvideoenabler-hack-enables-airplay-video-streaming-in-all-ios-apps.html) from Cydia, and now I can watch videos from any iPhone App!     :)

UPDATE: AirMedia Player is not so stable on windows and it was not updated since released.